# AES265 Python to C# conversion failed

Tags: python, c#, cryptography

I'm trying to convert few lines `Python` code into `C#` code. I'm facing an error where I don't know which line cuases that error. I have no idea about `Python` at all. I think I have made mistake of slicing sub array or decryption process then I rewrite with different ways such as `Buffer.BlockCopy` but no luck.

[Python source](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/whats-enc/blob/master/backend/whats-enc.py)

```
#Example grabbing JPEG instead of MP4
mediaurl = "url"
mediakey="UdoT3mfVvt3kMp0+MAybMlgVrnEyVAdxSamXQ+qbRog="
salt = "WhatsApp Image Keys"

mediaKeyExpanded = HKDF(base64.b64decode(mediakey),112,salt)
iv = mediaKeyExpanded[:16]
cipherKey = mediaKeyExpanded[16:48]
macKey = mediaKeyExpanded[48:80]

mediaData = urllib2.urlopen(mediaurl).read()
file = mediaData[:-10]
mac = mediaData[-10:]


decryptor = AES.new(cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
imgdata=AESUnpad(decryptor.decrypt(file))

with open('rob.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)

print("file written to rob.jpg")
```

C# code
[Hkdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hkdf/)

```
var hkdf = new Hkdf(System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

var mediakey = Convert.FromBase64String("UdoT3mfVvt3kMp0+MAybMlgVrnEyVAdxSamXQ+qbRog=");
var salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WhatsApp Image Keys");

var mediaKeyExpanded = hkdf.Expand(mediakey, 112, salt); //HKDF(base64.b64decode(mediakey), 112, salt)
var length = mediaKeyExpanded.Length;

var iv = mediaKeyExpanded.Skip(0).Take(16).ToArray(); //mediaKeyExpanded[:16]
var cipherKey = mediaKeyExpanded.Skip(16).Take(32).ToArray(); //mediaKeyExpanded[16:48]
var macKey = mediaKeyExpanded.Skip(48).Take(32).ToArray(); //mediaKeyExpanded[48:80]

var mediaData = File.ReadAllBytes("file.enc");
    length = mediaData.Length;
var fileLength = length - 10;
var file = mediaData.Take(fileLength).ToArray(); //mediaData[:-10]
var mac = mediaData.Skip(fileLength).Take(10).ToArray();//mediaData[-10:]

//decryptor = AES.new(cipherKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
//imgdata = AESUnpad(decryptor.decrypt(file))

using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged { 
    Key = cipherKey, IV = iv, Mode = CipherMode.CBC, KeySize = 256, BlockSize = 128
})
{
    rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(file))
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(cipherKey, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (var fsOut = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\file_decrypted.jpg", FileMode.Create))
    {
        int data;
        while ((data = cryptoStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
            fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
    }
}
```

[This is the file I'm trying to decrypt.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bx5jcah5ihyl0cn/encfile.rar/file)

Edit:
The image file is successfully created but cannot be open by any image viewer due to bad or unsupported format.

Comment: I suggest you to use `dynamic` instead of using `var`. this will make code very near to python use.

Comment: `mediaData.Skip(10)` should be `mediaData.Skip(length - 10)`, but that doesn't solve your problem. Make sure that RijndaelManaged has a block size of 128. Also, the padding might be different. Have you looked into the resulting file with a (hex) editor to see if there are differences?

Comment: I've edited my question. Still doesn't work

Comment: The counterpart to `AESUnpad()` in the Python code (i.e. `AESPad()`) uses _PKCS7 padding_ ([here](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/whats-enc/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py)) and thus differs, as Artjom B. already suspected, from the padding in the C# code, where _Zero padding_ is used. I would also check if `HKDF()` in the Python code and `Hkdf.Expand()` in the C# code give the same result, i.e. if `mediaKeyExpanded` is identical in both codes (to verify that both are functionally identical).

Comment: Changing to `PKCS7` gives me `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed`

Comment: C# doesn't perform any unpadding with _Zero padding_, but it does with _PKCS7_. This error message rather points to an error in the decryption itself. This results in a wrong plaintext that is inconsistent with _PKCS7_, whereupon the error message is displayed. If you keep _Zero padding_ the _PKCS7 padding_ bytes won't be removed. I suppose one of the problems is that the _hkdf's_ used are not functionally identical. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted by Artjom B., there is a bug in the C# code when determining the MAC, which is meanwhile fixed in the posted code.

The explicit setting of the key size to 256 bits or the block size to 128 bits, however, makes no difference, since these values are used by `RijndaelManaged` by default. This corresponds to AES, so it could also be applied e.g. `AesManaged`.

Apart from the bug in the MAC determination, there are two more bugs in the C# code:

- The counterpart to [`HKDF()`](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/whats-enc/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py) from the Python code for the C# code is:

  ```C#
  var mediaKeyExtracted = hkdf.Extract(mediakey, null);        
  var mediaKeyExpanded = hkdf.Expand(mediaKeyExtracted, 112, salt);
  ```

  This returns a value for `mediaKeyExpanded` that corresponds to the one determined in the Python code, that is (hex encoded):

  ```
  a02b98bd6ce9575c95cc938e39bb782ba5d6478c98c0e356ea7ee70b4900f3861db9528cd4490ca02789410b3c3aba4489ebcce2c153a015f213a331d147ba515450edd55f8ff03d8fce4760825351f16b2a23d371e30846c0492e259cabb263d63bc6e098280002cb125fc807a03a2b
  ```

  which gives the following values

  ```
    iv:        a02b98bd6ce9575c95cc938e39bb782b
    cipherKey: a5d6478c98c0e356ea7ee70b4900f3861db9528cd4490ca02789410b3c3aba44
    macKey:    89ebcce2c153a015f213a331d147ba515450edd55f8ff03d8fce4760825351f1
  ```

  Note that the variable called `salt` is actually not the *salt* but the *info* parameter (see [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-2), section 2).
- From the Python code, i.e. the functions [`AESUnpad()`](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/whats-enc/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py) and [`AESPad()`](https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/whats-enc/blob/master/backend/whatsapp.py) it can be determined that the Python code uses PKCS7 padding. Therefore instead of Zero padding, PKCS7 padding must be applied in the C# code, otherwise the PKCS7 padding from the encryption will not be removed:

  ```
  rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
  ```

  Note that PKCS7 does not actually need to be specified explicitly as it is the default. But then you have to remove the line that explicitly specifies Zero padding.

With these changes the [linked file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bx5jcah5ihyl0cn/encfile.rar/file) can be decrypted using the *mediaKey* `UdoT3mfVvt3kMp0+MAybMlgVrnEyVAdxSamXQ+qbRog=` and the *appInfo* `WhatsApp Image Keys` with the C# code (see also [here](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng#decryption)). The decrypted file is identical in content to the file decrypted with the Python code.

---

By the way: With the variables `file`, `iv`, `macKey` and `mac` from the C# code, the file can be validated according to the instructions (see [here](https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng#decryption)) as follows:

```
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(macKey);

byte[] ivFile = new byte[iv.Length + file.Length];
Array.Copy(iv, 0, ivFile, 0, iv.Length);
Array.Copy(file, 0, ivFile, iv.Length, file.Length);

byte[] macCalc = hmac.ComputeHash(ivFile);

byte[] macCalc10 = new byte[10];
Array.Copy(macCalc, 0, macCalc10, 0, 10);

bool verified =  macCalc10.SequenceEqual(mac);
```

Since the file to be verified and the data from which the keys (`cipherKey`, `macKey`) and the IV are generated are downloaded from the *same* place (as a *rar* file, see [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bx5jcah5ihyl0cn/encfile.rar/file)) this is rather a low protection.